# K8s CRD v.s. K8sClient/Watch

Tags: kubernetes

I saw two sytles to auth/manage K8s pods.

- CRD controller
- K8s-client Creat/Get/Watch

I'm more preferred on the second option as it's more simple and codes can be run/debug/test without K8s.

Here check with community experts on which cases better we should use CRD controller.

Thanks.

Comment: A custom resource controller internally uses the Kubernetes API watch mechanism.  If you weren't using a custom resource, what would you watch?  Do you have a specific use case you're thinking of?

Comment: "I'm more preferred on the second option as it's more simple and codes can be run/debug/test without K8s."  

I am not sure if this is entirely true. Kubernetes SIGs came up with controller-runtime and then CoreOS people built operator-sdk. Both of these components streamline a lot of things related to controllers/operators including their testing.

Comment: RE David and ashu, I think many cases don't need a CRD. Especially those user don't change CR after send it out. I understood CRD is necessary and best option for certain cases. Take a simple case as an example: I want to run N tasks one by one. May I say K8s-client watch + a status record DB (need it anyway) is better than define a CRD?

Comment: Did you manage to solve problem ?

Comment: To MaggieO, I still didn't get a clear answer.
My thoughts

Comment: Did you consider using operator - https://sdk.operatorframework.io/ ?